# Can we change the Programming Puzzles & Code Golf community image?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I think the image is downright ugly:

[image]

Only the beta communities have this sort of image, this isn't beta anymore so can we change it to something more attractive please??? It strains my eyes everytime I want to solve some programming challenges.

Something like this would look pretty good I'd say:

[image]

Comment: If you want, you can install this [userscript](https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-Design). Follow the instructions there, and the page should look better (my opinion).

Comment: Ugh, that suggested logo hurts my eyes :P

Comment: I think [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JPJAD.png) logo is downright ugly. Maybe we can think of something simple and slick until the final design arrives. [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uCOUi.png) would look pretty good, I'd say.

Comment: I relish in your downvotes -- I embrace it, whatever doesn't kill my reputation only makes me stronger.

Comment: Marking as [meta-tag:status-declined]; although we do have a good logo now, this proposal didn't really get addressed while it was active, the proposal didn't get factored in at all, and we got an icon with graduation, not while in beta.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Only the beta communities have this sort of image

was once true, but as the number of sites which are graduating has grown, a backlog has built up. The icon will be changed as part of a cohesive design change for the whole site.